# Queries on deeply nested object, match every key in nested object with mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I have a rather unusual structure, that looks something like this (it is actually more nested in reality):

```
{
  "2019-12-05": {
    "10": {
      "us": {
        "6631_10_s902381": {
          revenue: 30,
          approved: 14,
          clicks: 20,
          hosts: 10
        }
      },
      "fr": {
        "6631_10_s902381": {
          revenue: 60,
          approved: 4,
          clicks: 2,
          hosts: 1
        },
        "2631_11_s902381": {
          revenue: 20,
          approved: 7,
          clicks: 3,
          hosts: 0
        }
      }
    },
    "14": {
      "us": {
        "5630_12_9502345": {
          revenue: 20,
          approved: 4,
          clicks: 0,
          hosts: 0          
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "2019-12-06": ...
}
```

Initially I thought about using mysql for this structure, but there would be a lot of duplicates as **the deepest object contains the data that is specific to all the parameters above it** (there is no overlapping in data).

If I did this on Mysql, it would be like this:

```
date          hour          country         sub                       revenue   approved    clicks  hosts
2019-12-05    10            us              "6631_10_s902381"         30        14          20      10
2019-12-05    10            fr              "6631_10_s902381"         60        4           2       1
2019-12-05    10            fr              "2631_11_s902381"         20        7           3       0
2019-12-05    14            us              "5630_12_9502345"         20        4           0       0
2019-12-06    ...
```

I would have to create a unique/primary index on the combination of all fields until "revenue". As you can see there would be a lot of overlapping.

However, I will need to query the database things like, "get me all data of date == 2019-12-05 and country == us (so ignore the hour and the sub parameters)", and I don't know how I can achieve that with mongodb.
I tried:

```
db.reports.find({"2019-12-05.$.us": { $exists: true}})
```

But it didn't work.

**My questions are:**

1. **Do you have a suggestion for a better database or schema for my needs?**
2. **Is there a way to get my query to work in mongodb? Can you match every key in an object as I tried to apply on the 2-level-nested key?**

Answer (score 0):

You can't use identifiers `$` or `$[identifier]` in non-arrays for mongodb. I would suggest a schema restructure such as this:

```
{
  {
    "date": ISODate(date)
    "us": [
      "10": {...},
      "14": {...}
    ],
  },
  {
    "date": ISODate(date)
    "fr": [
      "10": {...},
      "14": {...}
    ],
  }
}
```

Note that I changed the date to an ISODate so that Mongo can more easily query for a date or date range when you would like to. Please also note that I don't know the significance of the number 10 and 14 in your data set, so I don't know if this structure is exactly right for you.

However, with this new data structure, you could now run a query like this:

```
db.collection.find({"us": {$exists: true}, date: {$gte: new Date(date at midnight)}, {$lte: new Date(date at 11:59:59pm)  })
```